New Operator with and without Parentheses
What is the main difference between using the new operator to create an array with trailing parentheses and without? That is, the difference between the following declarations
void* ptr = new int[5]();

and
void* ptr = new int[5];


Side note : new should not be uses like this in C++ (Have a look at C++ core guidelines R.11). And you really should avoid void*  too (unless you know what template programming and type erasure can do). When you want to allocate an array in  C++ use std::vector. So you should use something like std::vector<int> values(5); (where values is a meaningful name)

@Peter new int[5]; is default initialization. new int[5]() is the same as using {}, its value initialization.

@Peter though I agree that the duplicate misses to make the connection between {} and (). The question here is about () the dupe is about {} (the answer is the same though)

Perhaps of interest:  new int[5]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500}

@463035818_is_not_an_ai - The dupe reason says "is similar", not "is identical". And it does match the new int[5] part exactly.

@BoP what I said. Its not identical but similar enough

Details of the new expression are explained here. In your example there is
new type new-initializer

The type is an array of 5 integers in both cases. The () is the new-initializer. Details of initialization are explained in this section. For integers default initialization (no ()) means the elements are not initialized and value initialization means the elements are initialized with a 0 value.
